# convert data: Array to ArrayBuffer

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-lib.js

I need to convert a PDF data array type buffer into an ArrayBuffer. here's an example

```
this.templateService.get(data[0].templateId).subscribe({
          next: async (data) => {
            this.datatemplate = data.datatemplate  


this.datatemplate {type: 'Buffer', data: Array(185251)} // type of data
```

when i try to read this data using PDF-LIB,

```
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(this.datatemplate)
    const form = pdfDoc.getForm()
    const fields = form.getFields()
    fields.forEach(field => {
      const type = field.constructor.name
      const name = field.getName()
      console.log(`${type}: ${name}`)
    })
```

I've got this error

> TypeError: `pdf` must be of type `string` or `Uint8Array` or
> `ArrayBuffer`, but was actually of type `NaN`

any help please?

Comment: where are you initializing the `array` variable? please show all relevant code

Comment: As written, its hard to tell what you are passing in, but the error is saying the `array` variable is set to `NaN` which definitely is not an array

Comment: i edited my post. i'm getting PDF data from postgres database.

Comment: can you show this class/object that `this` is referring too?